# Avoid "copy&paste" method for stored procedure depending on parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have 50 stored procedures that I need to add a new location to. Is there an alternative for writing my stored procedures in the following way? (where I copy the same select statement for each location)

```
IF @LOCATION = 'Canada'
BEGIN
    SELECT location_id, location_description
    INTO #tempAssetHistoryCANADA
    FROM [SERVER20].[Shop_Canada].[dbo].[report_asset_history]
END

IF @LOCATION = 'USA'
BEGIN
    SELECT location_id, location_description
    INTO #tempAssetHistoryUSA
    FROM [SERVER20].[Shop_USA].[dbo].[report_asset_history]
END
```

I have a select statement that fires if the `@parameter` = "x" And then the exact same select statement, but from a different data source with the same structure if `@parameter` = "y".

I'm wondering if there is a better way to write these stored procedures because in the future when I need to add a new location I will need to update all 50 stored procedures, and copy each statement and slightly alter it for the new locations data? I've researched around and haven't found anything helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: you can use dynamic sql  https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/

Comment: Maybe instead of a different database for each location you make that a column in a single table. Then you only need a where clause. And when you add a new location you don't have to change anything. It would just work.

Comment: You could use dynamic SQL: build the query in a VARCHAR variable, then run it using EXEC or sp_executeSQL. For options/differences, see e.g. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/turgays/2013/09/17/exec-vs-sp_executesql/

Comment: Your having issues because some of your *data* has been mis-modelled as *metadata*. To wit, country names, that you want to be able to query for, are in an unqueryable location (embedded in the database names)

Comment: Why do you need to use different names for your temporary tables?

Comment: Hmm I think I misunderstood - are you getting different data from the two databases in each of the 50 SPs?

Comment: @JohnRC if that's the case, this really is a hot mess....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using suggestions from the answers and comments mentioning Dynamic SQL I came up with this little solution for myself. It's nicer then what Denis Rubashkin said because using his solution I would still have to copy the entire SQL query every time a new location is added. This way, I can just copy the 4 lines...

`IF @LOCATION = 'CANADA'

    BEGIN

    SET @location_server = 'SHOP_Canada'

    END`
...from the IF statement at the beginning whenever I want to add a new location, not the whole SQL statement. It will replace the server name with the correct name in the parameter and append its name to the temp tables.

```
@LOCATION varchar(50),
@sqlCommand nvarchar(2000),
@location_server varchar(75)

IF @LOCATION = 'CANADA'
BEGIN
    SET @location_server = 'SHOP_Canada'
END

IF @LOCATION = 'USA'
BEGIN
    SET @location_server = 'SHOP_USA'
END

SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT location_id, location_description

    into ##MarineShopAssetExpensesLTD_'+@location_server+'

    FROM [SERVER20].'+QUOTENAME(@location_server)+'.[dbo].[report_asset_history]

    INNER JOIN [SERVER20].'+QUOTENAME(@location_server)+'.[dbo].imtbl_asset ON [report_asset_history].asset_id = imtbl_asset.id

    GROUP BY location_id, location_description

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible way instead of using a dynamical query is to create a view:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.Locations
AS

SELECT location_id, location_description, 'Canada' AS location
FROM [SERVER20].[Shop_Canada].[dbo].[report_asset_history]

UNION ALL 

SELECT location_id, location_description, 'USA' AS location
FROM [SERVER20].[Shop_USA].[dbo].[report_asset_history]
```

And then using it:

```
SELECT location_id, location_description
INTO #tempAssetHistory
FROM [dbo].Locations
WHERE location = @LOCATION
```

If you have new tables `[SERVER20].[Shop_XXX].[dbo].[report_asset_history]` you will have to add them to your view.

Comment: That is a pretty good workaround, but the real solution would be to change the databases structure to a single, unified database where the location is just another column.

Comment: Of course, it is just a workaround, I know nothing about a possibility to change the database's structure.

Comment: Short of fixing the underlying database issues this is probably the best way to handle this.

Comment: Might there be a performance impact of a view being a union across tables in different databases, when the where clause applies outside the view. Wouldn't you be loading all the data from both databases before filtering out the unwanted rows?

Comment: @JohnRC I was just thinking the same thing.  I actually like your answer better. :-)

Comment: @JohnRC - bear in mind that a view is akin to a macro in some other languages - it's "expanded out" into queries that use it before optimization occurs. If the optimizer is doing a decent job (not by any means guaranteed) it will then push predicates down to the lowest point at which they can be evaluated and can *sometimes* demonstrate that no data access will be required. If your mental model is a view defines a query that "runs first" before the outer query works with its results, that's inaccurate.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you don't need a different #temp table for each location.  You're storing the same data columns in each.  Secondly, you could store the "From" clause in a table based on location and then use dynamic sql to select into your temp table.  I'll provide some code and example shortly.

```
DECLARE @fromClause VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)

--Explicitly create the temp table
CREATE TABLE #T (location_id int, location_description varchar(255) )

--Get the FROM clause
select @fromClause = fromClause from tblLocation WHERE location  = @LOCATION

--Build the Dynamic SQL
SET @sql = 'SELECT location_id, location_description ' + @fromClause

--Insert into your temp table
INSERT INTO #T execute ( @sql )

--View the results
SELECT * FROM #T
```

Here is tblLocation definition
[image]

Comment: This would work but is perpetuating a poor data design. Once you have to resort to dynamic sql and storing partial sql statements in a table it is clear sign that something is very off base.

Comment: I'm offering a solution to his problem, not telling them how to change their data design.

Comment: No need to be defensive. Yes as I said it works. But that data design is truly awful.

Comment: Man, i just suck at life...:-(

Answer (score 1):

Put the code that loads the temp table into table-valued function. Then call this function from all your other SPs that need the data

```
SELECT * INTO #TempAssetHistory FROM dbo.LoadTempAssetHistory(@Location)
:
:   Use the data
:
```

The LoadTempAssetHistory SP would look something like (CODE NOT TESTED):

```
CREATE FUNCTION LoadTempAssetHistory
(   
    @LOCATION Varchar(50)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(

        SELECT location_id, location_description

            FROM [SERVER20].[Shop_Canada].[dbo].[report_asset_history]
                    WHERE @LOCATION='CANADA'

        UNION 
            SELECT location_id, location_description
                FROM [SERVER20].[Shop_USA].[dbo].[report_asset_history]

                WHERE @LOCATION = 'USA'

)
```

Now you can amend the function when you have a new location (or decide to reorganise all your data) without needing to change 50 SPs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one table to store all selected data, use something like this:

```
DECLARE @country VARCHAR(20) = 'USA'

CREATE TABLE #tempHistory (country varchar(20), location_id int, location_description varchar(20))

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(max)
SET @sql = 'SELECT ''' + @country + ''' as country, location_id, location_description FROM [SERVER20].[Shop_' + @country + '].[dbo].[report_asset_history]'

INSERT INTO #tempHistory EXEC (@sql)
```

Or you can use more flexible solution to put the list of countries as a parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.prepare_tempHistory(@listOfCountries VARCHAR(max))
AS
    DECLARE @sql varchar(max)
    SET @sql = ''

    SELECT @sql = @sql + ' UNION ALL ' +
           'SELECT ''' + val + ''' as country, location_id, location_description FROM [SERVER20].[Shop_' + val + '].[dbo].[report_asset_history]'
    FROM dbo.fnSplit(@listOfCountries, ',')

    SET @sql = RIGHT(@sql, len(@sql)-11)

    INSERT INTO #tempHistory EXEC (@sql)
GO
```

but then you need a small function to split parameters into table:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnSplit
(
    @delimited nvarchar(max),
    @delimiter nvarchar(5)
) 
RETURNS @ret TABLE (val nvarchar(max))
AS
BEGIN
    declare @xml xml
    set @xml = N'<root><r>' + replace(@delimited,@delimiter,'</r><r>') + '</r></root>'

    insert into @ret(val)
    select r.value('.','varchar(max)') as item
    from @xml.nodes('//root/r') as records(r)

    RETURN
END
GO
```

Now you can prepare data on easy way:

```
CREATE TABLE #tempHistory (country varchar(20), location_id int, location_description varchar(20))

EXEC dbo.prepare_tempHistory 'USA,Canada,Mexico'

SELECT * FROM #tempHistory
```

for any additional country modify only the parameter

Comment: Assuming location is the same as in the table name

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by having a #Temp table for all your assists and checking against a location table in your DB, then calling the variable when the SP is executed:

Call the SP:

```
SP_Some_SP 'Canada'
```

Inside the SP

```
Declare @Location Varchar(100)
Declare @Location_ID int = (Select Location_ID from [Location] where Location_Description = @Location)


CREATE TABLE #TempAssetHistory
(
  location_ID int, 
  location_Description varchar(100) 
)

If Exists(Select Location_Description from [Location] where Location_Description = @Location )
BEGIN
    Insert INTO #TempAssetHistory
    Values(@Location_ID,@Location)
END
ELSE
BEGIN 
-- Do something
END
```

Answer (score 0):

As every SP is looking for different data, there is another, somewhat more drastic approach that you could use.

This approach requires that you put all the data SELECT statements for all 50 SPs into a single SP, say spDataLoad, which takes two parameters - a data set name and the location. The spDataLoad selects data based on which data set and which location are specified, and returns that requested data to the caller.

You will still need multiple select statements for each different combination of data set and location, but at least everything is in one single SP, and changes to the data will not affect all 50 SPs. If the tables and data for each location are the same, then you can subdivide the code into sections, one for each location, with identical code except for the database name corresponding to the location.

Using the code above as an example, if we choose 'AssetHistory' as the data set name then the code in your existing SPs would look like this:

```
:
:
CREATE TABLE #AssetHistory (
     location_ID int, 
     location_Description varchar(100) 
  );

INSERT INTO #AssetHistory EXEC spDataLoad @DataSet='AssetHistory', @Location=@Location;
:
:  use the data set
:
```

Now suppose you have another SP that requires the data set 'AssetDetails' then the code would be like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #AssetDetails (
     :
     :  Specification for Asset Details table
     : 
  );

INSERT INTO #AssetDetails EXEC spDataLoad @DataSet='AssetDetails', @Location=@Location;
:
:  use the data set
:
```

The stored procedure spDataLoad, with multiple sections, for each of the locations, with separate selects based on the requested data set might look like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spDataLoad
    @DATASET varchar(20)
    , @LOCATION Varchar(50)

AS
BEGIN

-- CANADA SECTION ------------------------------------
  IF @LOCATION = 'CANADA'
    BEGIN
        IF @DATASET = 'AssetHistory'
            SELECT location_id, location_description
            FROM [SERVER20].[Shop_Canada].[dbo].[report_asset_history]

       ELSE IF @DATASET = 'AssetDetails'
            SELECT 
               : Asset details data
            FROM [SERVER20].[Shop_Canada].[dbo].[report_asset_details]

       ELSE IF @DATASET = '....'
         : 
         : Etc, Etc for CANADA SECTION

    END;

-- USA SECTION ------------------------------------
    IF @LOCATION = 'USA'
    BEGIN
        IF @DATASET = 'AssetHistory'
            SELECT location_id, location_description
            FROM [SERVER20].[Shop_USA].[dbo].[report_asset_history]

       ELSE IF @DATASET = 'AssetDetails'
            SELECT 
               : Asset details data
            FROM [SERVER20].[Shop_USA].[dbo].[report_asset_details]

       ELSE IF @DATASET = '....'
         : 
         : Etc, Etc for USA SECTION

    END;

-- SOME OTHER SECTION ---------------------------
    IF @LOCATION = 'SOME OTHER'
    BEGIN
         : Same logic
    END

  RETURN 0;

END
```

To manage performance you would probably need to add defaulted parameters for filtering which can be specified by the caller, and add WHERE clauses into the data set selections.